# excel Auto input value based on figures in a table

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, excel-formula

I require some help, I have a simple table example as below:

Rates

**From - To - Rate**

- 51 - 60 - 2
- 61 - 70 - 4
- 71 - 80 - 6

Now on a spreadsheet, say line 1, I will have details, say cell A1 (Name) A2 (Marks) A3 (Rate), given in the example, the first person marks were 63, therefore, in cell A2 i will input 63 and in cell A3 I would want it to pick automatically based from the table above, which after inputting a formula in cell A3 it should give me a Rate of 4.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Prado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA, you can achieve this with simple Excel formula.

Note: you might need to replace `;` with `,` in my formula.

[image]